# Getting ClassNotFoundException when deploying Jersey application to Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, tomcat, jersey

I tried to set up a REST service according to this [article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html)

I installed a local Tomcat (that is running correctly) and set it up as a run configuration.
Unfortunatly, when building the application I receive

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

I copied the jersey .jar files into the WebContent/WEB-INF/lib directory as described and added the in my project properties.
I even tried to include a complete "bundle jar" of all necessary jar files provided for jersey on some sites to eliminate the possiblity of any dependency problems.

Comment: Since a war file is just a glorified zip file, make sure that you can navigate directly to that file in the location specified if you unzip it.

Comment: Where would I find my war file? I thought it to be located at build/ but the directory is empty after running my application
(This might already be wrong...)

Comment: Are you not deploying your application to Tomcat in a war file?

Comment: Well I thought I would but at least after the RUN failed I do not have a war file in my webapps directory